# EditText has an underscore bias? Pushy soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

When I click in a TextEdit in my Android app in the emulator, it wants to make any characters I type in underscored - why would that be? And then it brings up a "helpful" soft keyboard with a number of strange symbols on it - strange to me, that is; they're probably perfectly normal to somebody fluent in an Asian languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the default keyboard language for emulators is Japanese (I think). Just long press on the edit text, select "Input Method" from the context menu and change the language to English in the preference screen.

Comment: You're right. The options are:
1) Android Keyboard
2) Japanese IME (which, as you thought, is the default one selected)
3) Sample Soft Keyboard
4) (Chinese symbols)