# Android EditText Doesn't allow to clear the input characters

Tags: android, android-edittext

Underscore character is not appearing in my Edittext.

Comment: strange, i can do this .... question is off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: Try to change the Input Method in the emulator. Here I found one question that has a similar problem with the underscore  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460990/edittext-has-an-underscore-bias-pushy-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an event handler which was handling on back key_pressed event. Once I removed that it solved my problem.
The following is the code that I used for the event.
        loginDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBackPressed Called");
                Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(setIntent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```